# Refactorizar Consulta de mysql usada en bucle en el backend a una sola consulta en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, refactoring

Tengo la siguiente tabla de datos:
(no soy el autor de la tabla, y reconozco el error de separar la columna fecha: años y Mes)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*nota:* Esta tabla se le agregan datos que provienen de un archivo de interface de un servidor en unix.

Tengo un array con 3 fechas que se obtienen de manera dinámica en sus índices que debo utilizar:

```php
$fechas=[
    "2021-02"=> 26,
    "2021-01"=> 26,
    "2020-12"=> 27,
];
```

Entonces; hay 2 `foreach` anidados:
1 el que recorre un array con la lista de Productos.
2 el que recorre las fechas.

nota: este concepto esta incorrecto, hay que refactorizar el query.

---

Entonces; el query interno armado que hace las consultas luce así:

```php
    $stmtpre = "SELECT PVD_Year PVD_Month, PVD_PVDU, PVD_PVDP, PVD_Prod_Code FROM VEN_TempPVD WHERE PVD_Prod_Code='" . $codpro . "' AND PVD_Year=" . $año . " AND PVD_Month=" . $mes . ";";
```

La primera idea para Evitar estos bucles petardeando el servidor MyQql es pasar la lista de Productos dentro de un `IN` (perfecto):

```php
    $stmtpre = "SELECT PVD_Year, PVD_Month, PVD_PVDU, PVD_PVDP, PVD_Prod_Code FROM VEN_TempPVD WHERE PVD_Prod_Code IN ('" . $lista_codpro . "');";
```

El problema es las clausulas de Año y Mes, Si hago (Problema):

```php
    $stmtpre = "SELECT PVD_Year, PVD_Month, PVD_PVDU, PVD_PVDP, PVD_Prod_Code FROM VEN_TempPVD WHERE PVD_Prod_Code IN ('" . $lista_codpro . "') AND PVD_Year IN ('".$años."') AND PVD_Month IN ('".$meses."');";
```

***Resultado:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También intente agrupar con `group`; me lo recomendaron en los comentarios:

```php
SELECT PVD_Prod_Code, PVD_Year, PVD_Month, PVD_PVDU, PVD_PVDP FROM VEN_TempPVD WHERE PVD_Prod_Code IN ('00277','00285') AND PVD_Year IN ('2021','2020') AND PVD_Month IN ('02','01','12') GROUP BY PVD_Year, PVD_Month;
```

y el Resultado sigue trayéndome 6 registros y ahora me ignoro un producto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

me retorna 6 Registros cuando espero solo 3 por producto.

***Ejemplo de lo esperado:***

```
Cod_prod  Mes   Año     PVD_PVDU    PVD_PVDU
00277     02    2021    100         100
00277     01    2021    100         100
00277     12    2020    100         100
00282     01    2021    100         100
00282     02    2021    100         100
00282     12    2020    100         100
```

***No logro determinas si me hace falta `agrupar` o `agregar` clausulas a mi `where`, lo quwe intento es obtener solo los 3 registros esperados del ejemplo por producto ?***

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130630/discussion-on-question-by-arcanis-the-omnipotent-refactorizar-consulta-de-mysq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A.Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano) por la colaboración encontramos dos respuestas:

Utilizando las clausulas `AND` y `OR`:

```
SELECT PVD_Prod_Code, PVD_Year, PVD_Month, PVD_PVDU, PVD_PVDP FROM VEN_TempPVD WHERE PVD_Prod_Code IN ('00277','00285') AND ((PVD_Year='2020' AND PVD_Month ='12') OR (PVD_Year='2021' AND PVD_Month ='01') OR (PVD_Year='2021' AND PVD_Month ='02'))ORDER BY PVD_Prod_Code ASC, PVD_Year ASC, PVD_Month ASC;
```

Utilizando el Método `CONCAT` y la clausula `IN`:

```
SELECT PVD_Prod_Code, PVD_Year, PVD_Month, PVD_PVDU, PVD_PVDP FROM VEN_TempPVD WHERE PVD_Prod_Code IN ('00277','00285') AND CONCAT(PVD_Year, '-',PVD_Month) IN ('2021-02', '2021-01', '2020-12') ORDER BY PVD_Prod_Code ASC, PVD_Year ASC, PVD_Month ASC;
```

Resultado de las dos querys:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]