# Refactorizar Consulta de mysql usada en bucle en el backend a una sola consulta en mysql [Parte 2]

Tags: mysql, refactoring

hace un par de días colgué esta pregunta en el sitio:

[Refactorizar Consulta de mysql usada en bucle en el backend a una sola consulta en mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/491439/refactorizar-consulta-de-mysql-usada-en-bucle-en-el-backend-a-una-sola-consulta/491471#491471)

a la cual le logramos encontrar una respuesta, pero el día de hoy tengo un dato adicional que no se había tomado en cuenta:

Estos querys son funcionales si la consulta se realiza desde 1990 hasta junio de 2021, por que hay un solo registro por mes o periodo `1999-06` o `2021-05`:

Utilizando las clausulas `AND` y `OR`:

```sql
SELECT PVD_Prod_Code, PVD_Year, PVD_Month, PVD_PVDU, PVD_PVDP FROM VEN_TempPVD WHERE PVD_Prod_Code IN ('00277','00285') AND ((PVD_Year='2020' AND PVD_Month ='12') OR (PVD_Year='2021' AND PVD_Month ='01') OR (PVD_Year='2021' AND PVD_Month ='02'))ORDER BY PVD_Prod_Code ASC, PVD_Year ASC, PVD_Month ASC;
```

Utilizando el Método `CONCAT` y la clausula `IN`:

```sql
SELECT PVD_Prod_Code, PVD_Year, PVD_Month, PVD_PVDU, PVD_PVDP FROM VEN_TempPVD WHERE PVD_Prod_Code IN ('00277','00285') AND CONCAT(PVD_Year, '-',PVD_Month) IN ('2021-02', '2021-01', '2020-12') ORDER BY PVD_Prod_Code ASC, PVD_Year ASC, PVD_Month ASC;
```

Resultado de las dos querys:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo cual se consiguen los 3 registros de los periodos consultados.

Pero: ***a partir de junio 2021 hay dos registros por mes; y en este caso solo debe ser considerado el ultimo registro del periodo.***

he intentado utilizar `MAX` y `GROUP BY`:

```sql
    SELECT
        MAX(KeyIdT_VEN_PVD),
        PVD_Prod_Code,
        CONCAT(PVD_Year, '-', PVD_Month) AS PVD_Period,
        PVD_PVDU,
        PVD_PVDP
    FROM
        VEN_TempPVD
    WHERE
        PVD_Prod_Code IN('00277') AND CONCAT(PVD_Year, '-', PVD_Month) IN('2021-09', '2021-08', '2021-07')
    GROUP BY
        KeyIdT_VEN_PVD
    ORDER BY
        PVD_Prod_Code ASC,
        PVD_Year ASC,
        PVD_Month ASC;
```

y Obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el cual no es el resultado esperado; el resultado esperado es el que da el anterior post.

he creado un ejemplo mínimo aquí:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac62c97/1/0

***Update***

intente implementar `inner join` pero solo obtengo los datos de un producto:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ada23/3/0

```sql
    SELECT
        MAX(KeyIdT_VEN_PVD),
        PVD_Prod_Code,
        CONCAT(PVD_Year, '-', PVD_Month) AS PVD_Period,
        PVD_PVDU,
        PVD_PVDP
    FROM
        VEN_TempPVD
    WHERE
        PVD_Prod_Code IN('00277') AND CONCAT(PVD_Year, '-', PVD_Month) IN('2021-09', '2021-08', '2021-07')
    GROUP BY
        KeyIdT_VEN_PVD
    ORDER BY
        PVD_Prod_Code ASC,
        PVD_Year ASC,
        PVD_Month ASC;
```

***¿Cómo puedo obtener el ultimo registro de cada periodo?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya esta resuelto, mas que nada el problema era de lógica; se implemento un `INNER JOIN` y la clausulas IN y MAX debían ir en el sub-Query.

nuevo query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ada23/12/0

```sql
    SELECT
        KeyIdT_VEN_PVD,
        PVD_Prod_Code,
        CONCAT(PVD_Year, '-', PVD_Month) AS PVD_Period,
        PVD_PVDU,
        PVD_PVDP
    FROM
        VEN_TempPVD
    INNER JOIN(
        SELECT
            MAX(KeyIdT_VEN_PVD) last_PK
        FROM
            VEN_TempPVD
        WHERE
            PVD_Prod_Code IN('00277', '00278') AND CONCAT(PVD_Year, '-', PVD_Month) IN('2021-09', '2021-08', '2021-07')
        GROUP BY
            CONCAT(PVD_Year, '-', PVD_Month),
            PVD_Prod_Code
    ) AS S_T
    ON
        VEN_TempPVD.KeyIdT_VEN_PVD = S_T.last_PK;
```